# Overriding LogoutView.get

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I'm trying to override `LogoutView.get`, to delete an extra cookie.
This is my approach:

```py
class SignOutView(LogoutView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """Override get() to delete extra cookie that was set on login."""
        res = super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
        res.delete_cookie(settings.SESSION_API_KEY_COOKIE_NAME)
        return res
```

This does not work, the code doesn't seem to be called at all.
I don't understand why, when I override a different method, e.g. `dispatch`, it works as expected:

```py
class SignOutView(LogoutView):
    @method_decorator(never_cache)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        res = super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        res.delete_cookie(settings.SESSION_API_KEY_COOKIE_NAME)
        return res
```

But I would like to understand why overriding `get` doesn't work here.

According to [http://ccbv.co.uk/](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.contrib.auth.views/LogoutView/#get), the [Django sources](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.11.18/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L173) and my understanding of how class based views handle requests, I think I should be able to override `LogoutView.get`.
I'm using Django 1.11.18, but I don't think that matters here.

Is there anything obvious that I'm missing?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Did you set the `SignoutView` to be triggered in case of a logout? Just subclassing the view evidently is not enough to change to what view a logout call will go.

Comment: Thanks but yes it is hooked up in urls.py, and I'm using that URL: `url(r'^sign-out/$', auth_views.SignOutView.as_view(), name='sign_out',)`

Comment: It's a very old question now, but do you recall what error you were getting, and how it led you to conclude the override method wasn't being called?  I'm asking because I'm using Django 4.1.9 and had a similar use case, I needed to override the built in Logout call to perform an extra step.  Your question provided my answer, I just overrode the get() method and it's working.